# Какая буква по счёту в массиве

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть массив из букв

```
     string[] endtext2 = new string[] { "а", "б", "в",
 "г", "д", "е", "ё", "ж",
"з", "и", "й", "к", "л", "м", "н", "о", "п", "р", "с",
"т", "у", "ф", "х",
 "ц", "ч", "ш", "щ", "ъ", "ы", "ь", "э", "ю", "я","a","b","c","d","i","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t" ,"u","v","w","x","y","z"};
```

Есть к примеру буква у как узнать какая по счёту она в массиве

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Всё просто.

В общем случае вам поможет функция [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
char[] endtext2 = new char[]
    { 'а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л',
      'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш',
      'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я',
      'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', // наверное, тут была опечатка, да?
      'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r',
      's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
char c = ...;
int idx = Array.IndexOf(endtext2, c);
if (idx != -1) // допустим, что наш массив индексируется от нуля, как
{              // и все уважающие себя массивы
    // found at index idx
}
```

Можно ещё извратиться и использовать то, что буквы идут почти подряд, а с правильной локалью — точно подряд (http://ideone.com/SqCPPZ):

```
CultureInfo ics = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
CultureInfo rcs = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");

int findIdx(char c)
{
    string cs = c.ToString(ics);
    if (string.Compare(cs, "а", false, rcs) >= 0 &&
        string.Compare(cs, "я", false, rcs) <= 0)
    {
        // русская буква
        // выясним, где она относительно ё
        int compareToJo = string.Compare(cs, "ё", false, rcs);
        if (compareToJo < 0)
            return (int)c - (int)'а';
        else if (compareToJo > 0)
            return (int)c - (int)'а' + 1;
        else
            return 6; // номер ё в списке
    }

    if (string.Compare(cs, "a", false, ics) >= 0 &&
        string.Compare(cs, "z", false, ics) <= 0)
    {    
        return (int)c - (int)'a' + 33;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Но это вряд ли эффективнее простого поиска по таблице, как в первом варианте.

Comment: Ну зачем `else` после `return`?:) 

Извиняюсь

Comment: @Veikedo: для симметрии, конечно. :-) Эстетика кода не менее важна, чем правильность.

Обычно я пишу что-то вроде

    return
        (compareToJo < 0) ? (int)c - (int)'а' :
        (compareToJo > 0) ? (int)c - (int)'а' + 1 :
        6;

(что нужно читать как

    условие (compareToJo < 0) даёт (int)c - (int)'а',
    условие (compareToJo > 0) даёт (int)c - (int)'а' + 1,
    иначе 6

— приоритеты операций как раз подходят), но это чересчур ФП-стиль в рамках данной задачи.